# SCM changeset cannot be detected by Jenkins if building on different branches in the process

Tags: version-control, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build taking branch name as a parameter. Now the problem comes: if I run the build first against branch A, then on a different branch B, and finally come back to branch A, the code change set (revision) on branch A cannot be captured by Jenkins as there is build on B standing in the middle. Does anyone know how to keep change set still visible in this scenario?

Comment: What SCM are you using ?

Comment: @gareth_bowles I am using subversion.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set up builds against multiple branches is to have a separate job for each branch.  Since each job points to the specific branch, it will be able to detect the changes made to that branch.

If you have a lot of branches, this can get hard to maintain as job configuration changes will need to be made multiple times.  The [configuration slicing plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) and the [job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) can help you with this.

Comment: Well, in my case it is hard to set up a job per branch as the branch changes often thus is set as a parameter of the job.